Simultanuous Bluetooth and HMDI audio output in 24.04 LTS
We have Ubuntu connected to TV over HDMI for streaming.
My wife has good ears, but I need a hearing aid.
I am trying to have simultaneous HDMI and bluetooth audio output in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
In 22.04 LTS it was possible by using paprefs (Add virtual output for simultaneous output on all local sound cards), but this is no longer working. No virtual output is created.
Any workaround for 24.04 LTS?

Visit the support site of the app you used before and see if they have plans to make it work in Ubuntu 24.04 would be a good place to start.

Exactly which app do you refer to? There is nothing wrong with the bluetooth connection to my headset. The problem is that when the audio is directed to my headset, the TV speaker is silent, and when the TV speaker is on, my headset is silent. This is a pulseaudio problem, has nothing to do with any app.

This is the app from your own question. In 22.04 LTS it was possible by using paprefs

Ok, a terminology problem then, sorry. In my world, apps resides only on phones and tablets. As far as I understand, paprefs is a part of pulseaudio. Which support site do you mean?

It seems like pulseaudio has been replaced by pipewire on 24.04. Is this correct? If so, is there any way to arrange simultaneous/parallel output of audio to my two devices in pipewire?

Ok, it seems this question has died. No more answers or suggestions here.
